# How to query the database by clicking a link (single-file)

Tags: php, sql, ajax

To begin with, I have established a connection to my database.

I have also managed to successfully query the database when clicking a button (i.e. the query is

```
SELECT * FROM products
```

The columns of the 'products' table are: **id**, **name** and **price**.

What I want, is to make the following query when clicking the **price** link.

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY price DESK;
```

It is **MANDATORY** to only have a single file. That is to say, the **index.php** and only.

I have read a lot of stackoverflow topics but from what I have understood up until now, the problem is rooted in the fact that I have to necessarily have one file and only, and that when my page (i.e. index.php) reloads, all the GET and POST messages are simply gone.

Can anyone supply tested and working code?

Comment: Make your index.php page use a lot of if - elseif - elseif- elseif - else... If you get a post from the price button, query and show the result. Elseif you get a post from another button, query and show that result... Else show a page with buttons to click on.

Comment: Add params to your ajax call, and make sure to add `return false;` in the js functions called at link click.

Comment: You need to ORDER BY price **DESC** otherwise your query won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be close to what you want....if Im understanding correctly.

when you click a button/link,

```
<a href='www.yoursite.com?orderby=price'>PRICE</a>
<a href='www.yoursite.com?orderby=name'>NAME</a>
```

you would just link to different query strings.  ?orderby=price ?orderby=name etc  and then append that to the sql statement like so...

```
if(isset($_GET['orderby')){ $column = $_GET['orderby'];}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
if(!empty($column)){ $sql. = " ORDER BY ".$column." DESC";}
```

Now if there is not $_GET value, it just runs the original query, if there is values set in $_GET, then it appends the ORDER by...

Is this what you want?

Comment: It worked indeed!

I was trying to do something extremely close to what you posted, but I really cannot figure out why I didn't manage to make it work :-/

Anyhow, the code is actually working EXACTLY as it is supposed to work. So, thank you very much for your time mate! 

Cheers! :-)